# NextJS v13.5 app folder: about generateStaticParam and SSG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, app-router, static-site-generation

as seen in [NextJS Doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params):

> The generateStaticParams function can be used in combination with dynamic route segments to statically generate routes at build time instead of on-demand at request time.

so i need to create a dynamic route using /app/[dynamicroutename]/page.tsx to make it work.
my doubt is: how can i create a component that will be children of a main (not dynamic) route file like `/app/example/page.tsx` and `/app/example/ChildrenComponent.tsx` and still use generateStaticParams to fetch data inside ChildrenComponent and static generate it at build time?

i tried to use generateStaticParams in a non-dynamic route but it doesnt work as expected

Comment: Hi Erik, welcome to SO. I haven't used this feature, buttttttt wondering if you're hitting this bug - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53717 - maybe try generating params in layout.tsx as workaround?